# Comparing the value of two arrays and only returning the difference if a value is removed, not added

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I am working on a project with an array of values that could possibly change every 30 seconds. I need to compare the first `array` to the current `array` of values every time this runs and return the difference between the values ONLY if a value is removed.

For example if `array1 = [12, 14, 16]` and `array2 = [12, 16, 18]`, then I need to return `14` and do something with it. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

This is my current code, but it returns any difference between the two arrays:

```
function diffArr (array1, array2) {
  const temp = [];
  array1 = array1.toString().split(',').map(Number);
  array2 = array2.toString().split(',').map(Number);

  for (var i in array1) {
    if(!array2.includes(array1[i])) temp.push(array1[i]);
  }

  for(i in array2) {
    if(!array1.includes(array2[i])) temp.push(array2[i]);
  }

  return temp.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const array1 = [12, 14, 16, 20, 10]

const array2 = [12, 16, 18]

const diffArr = (array1, array2) => {
    const temp = array1.filter(ele => !array2.includes(ele))
    return temp.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}

console.log(diffArr(array1, array2)) // output = [ 10, 14, 20 ]
```